# Java JNI Error Help? Potential Package Hierarchy Error?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to do a call into a database that needs authentication and below (verbose) is what comes out for me, error in bold.

I think it's an issue with my packages but I couldn't figure it out. -- I'm an absolute newbie at this that's learning in trial by fire.

```
[Loaded java.lang.NoSuchMethodException from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Exception in thread "main" [Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/MissingArgumentException

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.MissingArgumentException

        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more

[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]

[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\rt.jar]
```

[error i'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKQ9m.png)